# Xcode 4 Deployment Target

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am trying to run an Xcode project but the software tries to run the app on my iPhone which is not connected. How can I tell Xocde to run the project on iPhone Simulator, not on my device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you not see a drop down box like the following? (If not, check that **View>Show Toolbar** is selected in the top menus.)

[image: Image of selection dropdown]

Also of note, click the right-hand side (ie, 'iOS Device') of the control, as this is actually a combination control, with the left-hand side used to select the full target, and the right, the device itself.